# Select Mysql commutative sum of each row

Tags: database, mysql

I want to achieve by mysql query

```
+------+---------+
| frq  | -any-   |
+------+---------+
|   10 |      10 |
|   15 |10+15=25 |
|   15 |25+15=40 |
+------+---------+
```

please help with code references, thanks

Comment: You mean you want the second column to be a running total of the first column?

Comment: Yes second column is the sum of all previous frqs

Answer (score 12, accepted):

MySQL Forum helped me !!!

```
mysql> set @my_var=0;
mysql> select frq, @my_var:=@my_var+frq as commutative_sum from `mytable`
```

This works well with my mysql routines.

Answer (score 12):

IMHO, that should be handled by program logic, and not SQL. If you still want to...:

```
   SELECT a.frq, sum(b.frq)
     FROM table a
     JOIN table b ON a.id >= b.id
 GROUP BY a.frq
```

Comment: What if i am have some order by clause with it. Then above logic wont work

Comment: You should be grouping BY a.id in order to get the intended results back.

Comment: @Ish Kumar: Because, as I said, you shouldn't be doing this from SQL. Keeping a variable with a running count will save you a lot of pointless struggle.

Comment: Thanks @Tordek for your contribution.